# Could not load file or assembly, newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json

I have a c# console application that is using JSON and it works fine when run on my development machine. When i try to move the application to another machine to run it i get the following exception when it comes to the part of my code which requires json:

> Could not load file or assembly, newtonsoft.json 4.5.0.0

I presume i need to download/install this on the machine i want to run the application on. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Newtonsoft.Json.dll from http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/107620 and place it in application's BIN folder.

Comment: Seems a bit silly to do this when OP has a copy of the right version of this file already.

Comment: Right, since OP didnt mention where the assembly resides (it may be gac'd) so suggested this option. Your answer assumes its already in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the missing assembly in the solution explorer (under references), right-click and select properties, then select

```
copy local: true
```

and the dll will be copied to your output folder and should be distributed with your program.